# Omni-Channel flow: how to specify a routing configuration?

Tags: visual-workflow, omnichannel, skills-based-routing

I am building a Flow that uses a Route Work element. I want to use "Run Skills-Based Routing Rules" and for that you must specify a Routing Configuration.

Two options are available for that: Select Routing Configuration and Use Variable. My system has exactly one Routing Configuration, but I cannot enter its name, nor its ID. Clicking in the field displays a busy cursor, but nothing can be found.

What am I doing wrong? A Routing Configuration does not have many attributes, by itself it's a simple thing. But apparently I need to do something before it can be used in a Route Work flow item.

[image]

Update: a workaround is to create a variable that contains the Id of the Routing Configuration, then use that variable. That works. But it is far from ideal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turns out to be related to [another issue](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/419427/how-to-trigger-omni-channel-skills-based-routing-from-a-flow) that I had with a flow that uses a Route Work action.

When I used the workaround that I added to my question, I got an error. After fixing that error, I was able to select the - only - available Routing Configuration in the system. So it looks like Salesforce only lets you enter Routing Configurations that satisfy all requirements. It's just a bit hard to figure that out.