# How to trigger Omni-channel skills-based routing from a flow?

Tags: visual-workflow, omnichannel, skills-based-routing

I have a record triggered flow that uses a "Route Work" action:

[image]

When I try to use this flow (both with Debug and for real), I get this error message:

> The routing configuration uses Skills-Based Routing Rules. To use the
> Omni-Channel Flow for routing, turn off Skills-Based Routing Rules on
> the routing configuration.

I don't understand: when I turn of Skills-Based Routing Rules on the routing configuration, all the applicable skills are gone as well and no skills-based routing is possible anymore.

I guess I don't understand how this is supposed to work. What I want to accomplish: trigger skills-based routing after a particular Case field has been changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After simply doing what the error message suggested - turning off the Skills-Based Routing Rules on the routing configuration - the flow works!

For me it is completely counterintuitive, but hey, it works now.